# Laravel: Tests failing with error 401 unathenticated

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have defined my tests like below

```php
  public function authenticated_users_with_permission_can_create_academic_year()
  {
    Permission::factory()->state(['name' => 'create academic year'])->create();
    $user = User::factory()->create();
    $user->givePermissionTo('create academic year');
    echo $user->can('create academic year') ? 'YES THEY CAN': 'NOPE THEY CANNOT';
    $response = $this->actingAs($user)->postJson('/api/academic-years', [
      'name' => $this->faker->year,
      'start_date' => $this->faker->date(),
      'end_date' => $this->faker->date(),
      ]);
    echo $response->content();
    $response->assertStatus(201);
  }
```

The response is below

```php
  Expected status code 201 but received 401.
  Failed asserting that 201 is identical to 401.

  at C:\path\to\AcademicYearTest.php:63
     59▕       'start_date' => $this->faker->date(),
     60▕       'end_date' => $this->faker->date(),
     61▕       ]);
     62▕     echo $response->content();
  ➜  63▕     $response->assertStatus(201);
     64▕   }
     65▕
     66▕   /**
     67▕    * POST /academic-year
```

In the log I can see 'YES THEY CAN' printed out indicating that a user actually exists and they have been given the correct permission.

In my routes I have

```php
Route::middleware(['auth:api', 'bindings'])->group(function () {
  Route::prefix('api')->group(function () {
    Route::resource('/academic-years', AcademicYearController::class);
  });
});
```

And Controller

```
  public function store(CreateAcademicYearRequest $request): JsonResponse
  {
    return response()->json(AcademicYear::createAcademicYear($request))->setStatusCode(201);
  }
```

The problem seems to be in the middleware

```
Route::middleware(['auth:api', 'bindings'])->group(function () {

});
```

When I remove the code outside the middleware, the test passes. Why is this happening?

Comment: Because the auth middleware requires an authenticated user which is not present during the tests you have lined out. Checking for an authenticated user via middleware and testing his capabilities are two different points. Maybe you want to disable the middleware during your tests, like stated here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/testing#disabling-middleware Not sure which version you are on and if it is the same way to go in Laravel 7 or 8.

Comment: @mynd disabling middleware was not an option, the reason for using `actingAs` was to authenticate the user. I have found the problem, I am providing a solution below, kindly check

Comment: I've totally missed the line where you were calling actingAs, my bad. Anyways. glad that you were able to track down the issue.

Answer (score 0):

After some research on possible problems, I found this [ActingAs Not working.](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/guides/actingas-not-working)

The problem was actually with how `actingAs()` works, below are some of its definition

```php
    public function actingAs(UserContract $user, $driver = null)
    {
        return $this->be($user, $driver);
    }
    public function be(UserContract $user, $driver = null)
    {
        if (isset($user->wasRecentlyCreated) && $user->wasRecentlyCreated) {
            $user->wasRecentlyCreated = false;
        }

        $this->app['auth']->guard($driver)->setUser($user);

        $this->app['auth']->shouldUse($driver);

        return $this;
    }
```

So by default `null` is being passed to the `guard()` function. Since we are testing an `api` guard hence the app is not authenticated.

To solve the problem hence the solution is to simply set the `driver` property to the `actingAs` function

I changed the line `$response = $this->actingAs($user)->postJson('/api/academic-years', [...])`; to `$this->actingAs($user, 'api')->postJson('/api/academic-years', [...])` and now my tests are authenticating as expected